# SaveAs or save dialog box for DOM in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to save  a DOM doc and the save method works just fine:

```
xDoc.Save "myFileName"
```

but I'd like the user to be able to pick the path and potentially the name.  So I tried:

```
xDoc = "Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show"
If myNum <> 0 Then
    XDoc = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)
End If
```

This opened a SaveAs dialog box but when I click ok I get a run time "object doesn't support this property or method".  I knew it probably wouldn't work but thought it made sense that it should.

Anyone know how to open a SaveAs dialog box with VBA to save a DOM(Document)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a problem, because you're using a literal string, rather than calling the method:

```
xDoc = "Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show"
'The value of xDoc has been assigned literally as above!!!
```

Instead, do this to instantiate a `FileDialog` object, and work with that. `Show` it, make sure that it's been used (if user cancels the `Show` will return `False` and then `.Execute` to do the `SaveAs` operation.

```
Dim fdlg As FileDialog
Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
fdlg.Title = "Save XML file as..."
fdlg.FilterIndex = 5  'Defaults to the XML Data file filter
If fdlg.Show() Then
    xDoc.Save fdlg.SelectedItems(1)         
Else: 
    MsgBox "File has not been saved!"
End If
```

NB: No error handling included in above code, expect it to fail or raise warning/etc if file already exists, etc. Modify as needed.

Comment: Would this be preferable to using the Application.getSaveAsFileName method?

Comment: @Dan in my opinion, yes. Working with the `FileDialog` object is cleaner to implement.

Comment: Also see minor revision to shorten the code a bit :)

Comment: xDoc is a MSXML.DOMDocument object, not a String object.  I apologize if I didnt make that clear.  I'm not sure this will work.  I don't have access to it now but when I do I'll try it.

Comment: no as originally written, it wouldn't work, but I've made a revision which I think should take care of it. let me know if you have trouble

Answer (score 0):

I've found something that works although it might not be the best approach.  If anyone has anything better, please post!

```
XDoc.Save (Application.GetSaveAsFileName(InitialFileName:="NewFile", FileFilter:="XML Data, *.xml", Title:="Save XML as"))
```

Comment: GetSaveAsFileName will work but you should separate out the processes of getting the filename and saving the file, in case the users cancels the dialog without choosing a path.

Comment: I have a process earlier on in the macro where an xml doc is loaded 5 times.  The path is set when the files are loaded into memory..  Is this not preferable?  Or, should I set up another process for the user to choose a separate place?

Comment: I can't answer that question, since it depends on exactly what the workflow is and what freedom you need the user to have in where the files end up.

Comment: Thanks! I Appreciate the feedback!